# Clean .txt and count most frequent words

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, word-count

I need to

1) Clean a .txt from a list of stopwords, which I have in a seperate .txt.

2) After that I need to count the 25 most frequent words.

This is what I came up with for the first part:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-

import re
from collections import Counter

f=open("text_to_be_cleaned.txt")
txt=f.read()
with open("stopwords.txt") as f:
    stopwords = f.readlines()
stopwords = [x.strip() for x in stopwords]

querywords = txt.split()
resultwords  = [word for word in querywords if word.lower() not in stopwords]
cleantxt = ' '.join(resultwords)
```

For the second part, I am using this code:

```
words = re.findall(r'\w+', cleantxt)
lower_words = [word.lower() for word in words]
word_counts = Counter(lower_words).most_common(25)
top25 = word_counts[:25]

print top25
```

**The source file to be cleaned looks like this:**

(b)

in the second paragraph, first sentence, the words ‘and to the High Representative’ shall be inserted at the end; in the second sentence, the words ‘It shall hold an annual debate’ shall be replaced by ‘Twice a year it shall hold a debate’ and the words ‘, including the common security and defence policy’ shall be inserted at the end.

**The stopwordlist looks like this:** 
this
thises
they
thee
the
then
thence
thenest
thener
them

**When I run all this, somehow the output still contains words from the stopword list:**
[('article', 911), ('european', 586), ('the', 586), ('council', 569), ('union', 530), ('member', 377), ('states', 282), ('parliament', 244), ('commission', 230), ('accordance', 217), ('treaty', 187), ('in', 174), ('procedure', 161), ('policy', 137), ('cooperation', 136), ('legislative', 136), ('acting', 130), ('act', 125), ('amended', 125), ('state', 123), ('provisions', 115), ('security', 113), ('measures', 111), ('adopt', 109), ('common', 108)]

As you can probablly tell, I just started learning python, so I would be very thankful for easy explanations! :)

Files used can be found here:

[Stopwordlist](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dzs96kw6nm24lpe/terrier-stopwords.txt?dl=0)

[File to be cleaned](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3m21r4wle8nxmn6/treaty_of_lisbon.txt?dl=0)

*EDIT: Added examples for the sourcefile, stopwordfile and the output.
Provided the sourcfiles*

Comment: Side note: I don't think you need the `[x.strip() ...` comprehension. It is redundant

Comment: @sshashank124 Without the x.strip there would be whitespace characters like /n at the end of each line, right?

Comment: Your code looks correct.  Are the stop words already lower case?

Comment: Why do you `' '.join` just to `re.findall` afterwards? Just keep it as a list. Also, filtering will be much faster if you convert `stopwords` to `set`. Apart from that it looks fine (assuming all stop-words are already in `lower` case).

Comment: @James Yes the stopwords are all lower case, it is essentially a list of words, one per line, in a seperate .txt file.

Comment: @tobias_k tbh, that´s what I found here on stackoverflow.

Comment: Getting 404 error on your files. Can you add a short excerpt to the question itself?

Comment: @tobias_k I just updated the file link, it should work now. I already provided excerps of both, the stopword list and of the text to be cleaned. Do you need anything more? Or could you clarify what you mean by the excerpt, so I can provide all information needed?

Comment: The excerpt you posted in comments was not consistent; the counts were much higher (like in the original text). However, with your files, I can not reproduce the problem. Just swapping the `querywords = ` line for `querywords = re.findall(r'\w+', txt)`, neither words like `"the"` nor numeric strings like `"1"` appear in the final counts.

Comment: That is weird, I tried again by downloading everything again and starting over in a new directory just in case, but it still didn´t work. However the code from @Jared Goguen seems to do the job. But that you very much for your effort and help, especially for the explenations! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost there, the major error is that you are running the regex `\w+` to group the words *after* you "cleaned" the words produced by `str.split`. This doesn't work because punctuation will still be attached to the `str.split` result. Try the following code instead.

```
import re
from collections import Counter

with open('treaty_of_lisbon.txt', encoding='utf8') as f:
    target_text = f.read()

with open('terrier-stopwords.txt', encoding='utf8') as f:
    stop_word_lines = f.readlines()

target_words = re.findall(r'[\w-]+', target_text.lower())
stop_words = set(map(str.strip, stop_word_lines))

interesting_words = [w for w in target_words if w not in stop_words]
interesting_word_counts = Counter(interesting_words)

print(interesting_word_counts.most_common(25))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works!
If I may ask you some questions, so I can understand what you just did there, that would be great! :)

1) Is the encoding absolutley necessary? Because it produces an error, and the code seems to work without it.

2) What are you doing here: `set(map(str.strip, stop_word_lines))`?

Comment: (1) No, I just added it to make the code work in Python 3.X, 
(2) This is equivalent to `set([word.strip() for word in stop_word_lines])`

Comment: Well, that's basically exactly the same thing I did. I wonder why it worked here, and did not (for OP) with my code...

Comment: @Tobias tbh, probably because it was given as a single code block rather than individual lines separated by explanations. OP probably made errors trying to implement your comments in their code

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of a wild guess, but I think the problem is here:

```
querywords = txt.split()
```

You just split the text, which means that some stop words might still be glued to punctuation and thus are not filtered in the next step.

```
>>> text = "Text containing stop words like a, the, and similar"
>>> stopwords = ["a", "the", "and"]
>>> querywords = text.split()
>>> cleantxt = ' '.join(w for w in querywords if w not in stopwords)
>>> cleantxt
'Text containing stop words like a, the, similar'
```

Instead, you could use `re.findall` like you did later in your code:

```
>>> querywords = re.findall(r"\w+", text)
>>> cleantxt = ' '.join(w for w in querywords if w not in stopwords)
>>> cleantxt
'Text containing stop words like similar'
```

Note, however, that this will split compound words like `"re-arranged"` into `"re"` and `"arranged"`. If that's not what you want, you could also use this to just split by whitespace and then trim (some) pnuctuation characters (there might be more in the text, though):

```
querywords = [w.strip(" ,.-!?") for w in txt.split()]
```

Changing just that one line seems to fix the problem for the input files you provided.

The rest looks okay, though there are a few minor points:

- you should convert `stopwords` to a `set` so the lookup is O(1) instead of O(n)
- make sure to `lower` the stop words if they are not already
- no need to `' '.join` the cleaned text if you intent to split it again right afterwards
- `top25 = word_counts[:25]` is redundant, the list is already at most 25 elements long

Comment: I now changed the `stopwords` to a `set` and used the `re.findall` part. That improved it a bit, now the numbers (1,2,3 and so on) are gone, but the output still contains words like "the" which are in the stopwords.txt. Just to make sure, how would I lower the stopwords? `.lower` doesn´t work I guess?

Comment: @Cold2Breath `[x.strip().lower() for x ...]` like you did in the lookup. How exactly does your text look? Can you post a small example that shows those problems?

Comment: Thanks!
Yes sure, the text looks like this: 
""" on the application of the principles of subsidiarity and proportionality;

(c)
 

by taking part, within the framework of the area of freedom, security and justice, in the evaluation mechanisms for the implementation of the Union policies in that area, in accordance with Article 61 C of the Treaty on the Functioning of the European Union, and through being involved in the political monitoring of Europol and the evaluation of Eurojust's activities in accordance with Articles 69 G and 69 D of that Treaty; """

Comment: The output looks like this:  [('article', 911), ('european', 586), ('the', 586), ('council', 569), ('union', 530), ('member', 377), ('states', 282), ('parliament', 244), ('commission', 230), ('accordance', 217), ('treaty', 187), ('in', 174), ('procedure', 161), ('policy', 137), ('cooperation', 136), ('legislative', 136), ('acting', 130), ('act', 125), ('amended', 125), ('state', 123), ('provisions', 115), ('security', 113), ('measures', 111), ('adopt', 109), ('common', 108)]

Comment: And the stopwordfile like this: x
y
your
yours
yourself
yourselves
you
yond
yonder
yon
ye
yet
z
zillion
j
u
umpteen
usually
us
username
uponed
upons
uponing
upon
ups
upping
upped
up
unto
until
unless
unlike
unliker
unlikest
under
underneath
use
used
usedest
r
rath
rather
rathest
rathe
re
relate
related
relatively
regarding
really
res
respecting
respectively
q
quite
que
qua
n
neither
neaths
neath
nethe
nethermost
necessary
necessariest
necessarier
never
nevertheless
nigh
nighest
nigher
nine
noone
nobody

Comment: If you´d like, I can provide the full files for reproduction purposes!

Comment: @Cold2Breath I'd much prefer if you could just add an excerpt of those files that still shows the problem to the question itself (using the "edit" button).